# Erratic behaviour with T1 mathematical fonts on different systems

Tags: math-fonts

I am new using T1 mathematical font. I installed all the Libertinus Math font on my computer and laptop (both with ubuntu). I also use Kile to write my documents. Nevertheless I have a kind of erratic behaviour. Let see. My  preamble is simply:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    math-style=french,
    bold-style=upright,
    partial=upright,
    nabla=upright
]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
$a<b\leq c$
\end{document}
```

But the result completely differs between the two systems.

- The first one gives:
  [image: First sytem]
- While the second gives:
  [image: Second system]

You can appreciate the difference right? Somebody could help me to solve this please?

The first log is:

```
*****
*****     LuaLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/xxx/Dropbox"
*****     lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(./test.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux
))
 484 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 52 glue_spec
, 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:19,3:5,4:3,5:23,6:1,7:24,8:5,9:7
</home/xxx/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf></home/xxx/.local
/share/fonts/LibertinusMath-Regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 4075 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

and the second is

```
*****
*****     LuaLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/xxx/Dropbox"
*****     lualatex --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
(using read cache: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic /home/xxx/.texlive2
017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.092 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regular.luc)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load luc: /home
/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-bold.
luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otl/lmroman12-italic.luc)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/libertinusserif-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusserif-bolditalic.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusserif-b
old.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/f
onts/otl/libertinusserif-italic.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinussans-regular.luc)(load luc: /hom
e/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinussans
-bold.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic
/fonts/otl/libertinussans-italic.luc)(load luc: /home/xxx/.texlive2017/tex
mf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusmono-regular.luc)(load luc: /ho
me/xxx/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusmat
h-regular.luc) (./test.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.ma
p}] (./test.aux))
 391 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 4 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:19,3:6,4:2,5:23,6:7,7:18,8:5,9:6
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/libertinusserif
-regular.otf></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/li
bertinusmath-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 4197 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: T1? what difference are you seeing, hard to tell the natural size or zoom level from the image

Comment: You right. let see the relative high between the extremity of < and the letter also you can observe the baseline of the second sign is lower in the first example. I said T1 because I read Libertinus is a T1 font....

Comment: It is more or less impossible to debug anything from an image, show the logs of the two runs. "T1` usually refers to the latex 8bit text encoding or to type 1 postscript fonts, neither of which are being used here. and show the output of the pdffonts utility on the two pdf.

Comment: also are you using xetex or luatex

Comment: with texlive 2020 [the output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4tkw.png)

Comment: Dear David, thanks you. Your version seems to fit with the first example I gave. Also I use Lualatex. I run pdffonts on both system and it results to be the same:

"CEUYVU+LibertinusMath-Regular        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0" and 
"VBSBYN+LibertinusSerif-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0". The first 6 letters (like CEUYVU) changed on both systems.

Comment: the uppercase bit is just a random string so that the subset font generated for the glyphs used is unique. Not sure if there was an early version of libertinus math with smaller <= operators, seems odd. what system made your second image?

Comment: I edit my post with the logs. Since I deal with two versions of Tex-live I should update I think :s Also I will check a source to update both fonts on both system!

Comment: I both print screen and gimped them. It is faithful to what I see on my screen.

Comment: 2017 is pre-history for luatex

Comment: Ok! My laptot works with 18.04 LTS / I will update! Hope to work well with the update. Anyway I now some new stuffs to debug myself now. Many thanks!

Comment: it really looks like a different font rather than a luatex change, you might want to check the change logs for the font project or simply install the latest Libertinus  fonts into the older system. I'm out though: I don't think I can debug more from here:-)